# How to handle strings containing several tags (index terms) using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataset where one particular column (`'Genres'`) contains strings with multiple tags, separated by commas.

[This is the dataset.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U0OF.png)

I need to process these strings to extract the data. 
Is there any way to clean up that column to get proper values to work with?

Comment: Don't post your data as an image. And please add your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings in your `Genres` column are meant to be lists of tags. To be able to work with that data, I would recommend to turn them into factors, i.e. create a separate column for each tag that indicates to which rows the tag applies. You can do it like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# small subset of your data for demonstration
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Sudoku', 'Reversi', 'Morocco'], 
                   'Genres': ['Games, Strategy, Puzzle', 
                              'Games, Strategy, Board', 
                              'Games, Board, Strategy']})
display(df)
```

```
    Name        Genres
0   Sudoku      Games, Strategy, Puzzle
1   Reversi     Games, Strategy, Board
2   Morocco     Games, Board, Strategy
```

```py
# split each of the strings into a list
df['Genres'] = df['Genres'].str.split(pat=',')

# collect all unique tags from those lists
tags = set(df['Genres'].explode().values)

# create a new Boolean column for each tag
for tag in tags:
    df[tag] = [tag in df['Genres'].loc[i] for i in df.index]

display(df)
```

```
    Name     Genres                     Board   Games   Puzzle  Strategy
0   Sudoku   [Games, Strategy, Puzzle]  False   True    True    True
1   Reversi  [Games, Strategy, Board]   True    True    False   True
2   Morocco  [Games, Board, Strategy]   True    True    False   True
```

Note this code is not optimized for speed. I just wanted to show how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
df['Genre'].str.split(",", n=1, expand=True)
```

put value of n by your own choice it will split on that many ","
Then choose a column that you want